# How to initialize reactive form at service and than inject to component

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components

How to initialize reactive form at service and than inject to each component?

I have 2 components and a service. Both components have same form becuse its just an exam to type at one component and display at other.

```html
  -----service----


    
public form: FormGroup;

 constructor(
    private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder
  ) 

 createform(sfm) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.formGroup(sfm);
  }






-------input and ouptu components --------



 constructor(
    private service: Service
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const sfm = new InputForm();
    this.service.createform(sfm);

}
```

This gives an error that form its not initialized.

Comment: Do you return the `FormGroup` from the service back to the components?

Comment: What is `RxFormBuilder` here? Where are you importing it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your form is going to be leveraged by the `Component` it would make sense to return the generated form from the Service to the Component.

Your service should generate the Form based on some data too, so that your form could be initialized with some data.

That being said, return the form from the service method:

```
constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder
)

createForm(sfm) {
  return this.formBuilder.formGroup({
    /*Generate form based on sfm here*/
  });
}
```

Now you can call the `createForm` method in your Component and expect it to return a `FormGroup`:

```
userForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private service: Service
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const initialData = {
    name: 'John'
  };
  this.userForm = this.service.createForm(initialData);
}
```

You can then use this form in the template as usual:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  ...
</form>
```

---

> You might want to read through [**this article on AngularInDepth**](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-i-increased-the-performance-of-an-extremely-deeply-nested-angular-reactive-form-by-380-c1b18ea668db) where I've done exactly that.

Comment: yes, this work. im able to get and pass data from input component to service. 
How can i pass values that change with time, from service to second component without using Subject ?

Comment: That would completely depend on your use case. Would you please consider asking another question with some details on the use case? That would make this thread more focused on just one problem. Thanks :)